# No Runtime can be found in Worklight Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, worklight-console

I am trying to set up test environemnt for worklight project. Every thing looks like started successfully without any errors , however, the worklight console says 'No runtime configuration could be found" . And I can not access my application in browser either. However, AppCenter is available.

The system is set up in `Redhat` OS, `Worklight` version 6.2, `DB2` as database and `WS-Liberty 8.5` as server. As suggested in different `SO` questions, I tried cleaning up the workarea of liberty server, clean-built and deploy, tried using java 1.6 instead of java 1.7 but nothing has worked. 
Thanks for spending your time in this question and any inputs. If you need any additional details, please let me know .

**EDIT: 
below are the logs, tried to cut out irrelevant messages :**

**Websphere details from log message:**

```
    ********************************************************************************
    product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.2 (wlp-1.0.5....)
    wlp.install.dir = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
    java.home = /root/Downloads/jre1.6.0_45
    java.version = 1.6.0_45
    java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.6.0_45-b06)
    os = Linux (2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64; amd64) (en_US)

********************************************************************************
```

**Relevant logs during server start up :**

```
    [8/14/14 10:07:09:966 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 79  WorklightPU  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.2.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[8/14/14 10:07:10:740 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Worklight Administration Services.


[8/14/14 10:07:11:696 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/wladmin
[8/14/14 10:07:11:697 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[8/14/14 10:07:12:258 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 2371  WorklightPU  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:12:445 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: analytics.
[8/14/14 10:07:12:445 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module analytics has been bound to default_host.


[8/14/14 10:07:12:446 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://hqdvwkl001:9080/_analytics/
[8/14/14 10:07:12:447 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [worklight-management-service]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[8/14/14 10:07:12:448 CDT] 00000023 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[8/14/14 10:07:12:450 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 2562  WorklightPU  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
[8/14/14 10:07:12:522 CDT] 00000023 springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext I Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@dcd88ea: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Aug 14 10:07:12 CDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy


[8/14/14 10:07:16:528 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : Apache Derby
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)
[8/14/14 10:07:16:617 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStore             I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=WorklightManagementPU-derby with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@43e3cae, openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add')}
[8/14/14 10:07:16:817 CDT] 00000018 com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource        I FWLSE0187I: jdbc/WorklightReportsDS data source is disabled. No connection opened.  [project <AppName>]
[8/14/14 10:07:16:838 CDT] 00000018 ringframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightReportsPU'
[8/14/14 10:07:16:841 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.2.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.


/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/Worklignt_CE_Dev/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/79/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/<AppName>/<AppName>/widget-resources
[8/14/14 10:07:17:261 CDT] 00000018 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[8/14/14 10:07:17:291 CDT] 00000023 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister             I FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin,qualifier=worklightadmin
[8/14/14 10:07:17:295 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 89  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:17:484 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 278  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary" (Apache Derby 10.8.2.2 - (1181258) ,Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)).
[8/14/14 10:07:17:493 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 4.17.29
[8/14/14 10:07:17:495 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStore             I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=WorklightManagementPU-derby with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@4e3d24d8, openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add')}


[8/14/14 10:07:18:017 CDT] 0000001b com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister             I FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin_WL_Config,qualifier=worklightadmin
[8/14/14 10:07:18:030 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 69  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:18:230 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 269  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).
[8/14/14 10:07:19:253 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 2046  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:317 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 2110  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:321 CDT] 00000023 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6873 ms


[8/14/14 10:07:19:329 CDT] 00000023 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I Worklight admin servlet context listener initialized
[8/14/14 10:07:19:331 CDT] 00000023 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I FWLSE3199I: ========= Worklight Admin Services version 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709 started.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:382 CDT] 00000023 org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet          I The system is using the com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementServiceServlet JAX-RS application class that is named in the javax.ws.rs.Application init-param initialization parameter.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 4.17.29
[8/14/14 10:07:19:399 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseFromDataSource=true
[8/14/14 10:07:19:399 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUrl=jdbc:db2://10.80.25.54:60006/APPCNTR
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriver=IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriverVersion=4.17
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseProduct=DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseVersion=SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUser=<AdminUserId>
[8/14/14 10:07:19:401 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData            I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=appcenterdb-db2 with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@2d43fc61}


[8/14/14 10:07:19:915 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application appcenterconsole.
[8/14/14 10:07:20:038 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R 237  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:20:058 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ApplicationCenterConsole.


[8/14/14 10:07:20:231 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.065 seconds.
[8/14/14 10:07:20:324 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R 523  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).
[8/14/14 10:07:20:384 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 2423  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.



[8/14/14 10:07:09:966 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 79  WorklightPU  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.2.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[8/14/14 10:07:10:740 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Worklight Administration Services.


[8/14/14 10:07:11:696 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/wladmin
[8/14/14 10:07:11:697 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[8/14/14 10:07:12:258 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 2371  WorklightPU  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:12:445 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: analytics.
[8/14/14 10:07:12:445 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module analytics has been bound to default_host.


[8/14/14 10:07:12:446 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://hqdvwkl001:9080/_analytics/
[8/14/14 10:07:12:447 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [worklight-management-service]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[8/14/14 10:07:12:448 CDT] 00000023 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[8/14/14 10:07:12:450 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 2562  WorklightPU  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
[8/14/14 10:07:12:522 CDT] 00000023 springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext I Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@dcd88ea: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Aug 14 10:07:12 CDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy


[8/14/14 10:07:16:528 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : Apache Derby
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver
[8/14/14 10:07:16:529 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)
[8/14/14 10:07:16:617 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStore             I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=WorklightManagementPU-derby with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@43e3cae, openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add')}
[8/14/14 10:07:16:817 CDT] 00000018 com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource        I FWLSE0187I: jdbc/WorklightReportsDS data source is disabled. No connection opened.  [project <AppName>]
[8/14/14 10:07:16:838 CDT] 00000018 ringframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightReportsPU'
[8/14/14 10:07:16:841 CDT] 00000018 SystemErr                                                    R 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-2] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.2.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.


/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/Worklignt_CE_Dev/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/79/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/<AppName>/<AppName>/widget-resources
[8/14/14 10:07:17:261 CDT] 00000018 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[8/14/14 10:07:17:291 CDT] 00000023 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister             I FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin,qualifier=worklightadmin
[8/14/14 10:07:17:295 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 89  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:17:484 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 278  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary" (Apache Derby 10.8.2.2 - (1181258) ,Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.8.2.2 - (1181258)).
[8/14/14 10:07:17:493 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:17:494 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 4.17.29
[8/14/14 10:07:17:495 CDT] 0000001b com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStore             I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=WorklightManagementPU-derby with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@4e3d24d8, openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add')}


[8/14/14 10:07:18:017 CDT] 0000001b com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister             I FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=WorklightAdmin_WL_Config,qualifier=worklightadmin
[8/14/14 10:07:18:030 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 69  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:18:230 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 269  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).
[8/14/14 10:07:19:253 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 2046  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:317 CDT] 00000023 SystemErr                                                    R 2110  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-5] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:321 CDT] 00000023 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6873 ms


[8/14/14 10:07:19:329 CDT] 00000023 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I Worklight admin servlet context listener initialized
[8/14/14 10:07:19:331 CDT] 00000023 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I FWLSE3199I: ========= Worklight Admin Services version 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709 started.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:382 CDT] 00000023 org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet          I The system is using the com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementServiceServlet JAX-RS application class that is named in the javax.ws.rs.Application init-param initialization parameter.
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8203I: Database product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8204I: Database product version : SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:19:398 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper      I DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 4.17.29
[8/14/14 10:07:19:399 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseFromDataSource=true
[8/14/14 10:07:19:399 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUrl=jdbc:db2://10.80.25.54:60006/APPCNTR
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriver=IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseDriverVersion=4.17
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseProduct=DB2/LINUXX8664
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseVersion=SQL10053
[8/14/14 10:07:19:400 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R dataBaseUser=<AdminUserId>
[8/14/14 10:07:19:401 CDT] 0000001a com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData            I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=appcenterdb-db2 with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@2d43fc61}


[8/14/14 10:07:19:915 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application appcenterconsole.
[8/14/14 10:07:20:038 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R 237  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:07:20:058 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ApplicationCenterConsole.


[8/14/14 10:07:20:231 CDT] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.065 seconds.
[8/14/14 10:07:20:324 CDT] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R 523  appcenterdb-db2  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-3] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).
[8/14/14 10:07:20:384 CDT] 0000001b SystemErr                                                    R 2423  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-4] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
```

**Logs created while accessing worklight console:**

```
[8/14/14 10:11:36:895 CDT] 00000066 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStoreUtil         I dereferenceProperties Handling propName=ibm.worklight.admin.db.jndi.name propValue=java:comp/env/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS
[8/14/14 10:11:36:895 CDT] 00000066 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStoreUtil         I dereferenceProperties Handling propName=ibm.worklight.admin.db.openjpa.Log propValue=
[8/14/14 10:11:36:895 CDT] 00000066 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStoreUtil         I dereferenceProperties Handling propName=ibm.worklight.admin.db.type propValue=
[8/14/14 10:11:36:898 CDT] 00000066 com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStore             I constructor Creating EntityManagerFactory for persistence-unit=WorklightManagementPU-derby with properties: {openjpa.ConnectionFactory=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@154b37e5, openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings=buildSchema(SchemaAction='add')}
[8/14/14 10:11:36:941 CDT] 00000066 SystemErr                                                    R 20  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-7] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[8/14/14 10:11:36:942 CDT] 00000066 SystemErr                                                    R 22  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-7] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary" (DB2/LINUXX8664 SQL10053 ,IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.17.29).
[8/14/14 10:11:37:236 CDT] 00000066 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Bean '*' does not exist.
[8/14/14 10:11:37:236 CDT] 00000066 com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService              I No mxbeans found
[8/14/14 10:11:37:380 CDT] 00000074 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Bean '*' does not exist.
[8/14/14 10:11:37:381 CDT] 00000074 com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService              I No mxbeans found
```

**Screen shot of worklight console with message:**

[image]

Let me know if any additional information is needed for any inputs.

Comment: What version of Liberty Profile is being used?  Is it 8.5, 8.5.5, 8.5.5.2, etc.?  There is an issue in 8.5.5.2 that can cause problems like this - I'd need to see the log files from your Liberty Profile server to be able to tell for sure.

Comment: @patbarron , it is 8.5.5.2 . updating logs. sorry about last misleading comment.

Comment: Please downgrade to 8.5.5.1; 8.5.5.2 is incompatible with Worklight 6.2; also make sure your Worklight Studio build is from August 1st.

Comment: will update you once I complete the downgrade. thanks for the input @IdanAdar

Comment: @Jimmy - I will add this as an answer.  If you find that the downgrade resolves the issue for you, please mark this as "Answered".  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to an issue in Liberty Profile 8.5.5.2.  The issue is tracked as APAR [PI17830](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI17830).  The fix for this issue is currently planned for Liberty Profile 8.5.5.3, but that is not yet available.

In the interim, please downgrade to Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1, and also ensure that you are using the August 1st (or later) build of Worklight Studio.

Comment: That resolved one issue, now my application is available. However, the worklight console still says `runtime not found`. For the meantime, I will just upvote this answer as it fixed part of my problem. I would really appreciate if you have additional inputs. let me know what information do you need.

Comment: Double-check your .war deployment, if it's not getting 'seen' by the application server, you will not see anything else in the Worklight Console.

Comment: @IdanAdar , thanks for the help . However I am having some problem that might be relevant to this same problem. I would like to request you both  to see it if you guys have time. Here is the link of new question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333005/no-mbean-found-for-worklight-project . Thanks guys.

Comment: for any user visiting this question, follow the link in above comments. it is resolved. Run time could not be found in worklight console is resolved .