# MobileFirst - WL 6.3 - Liberty 8.5.5.5 (Latest) - No Runtime can be found in Worklight Console

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I installed WL 6.3 on WAS Liberty 8.5.5.5 (the latest as of today) and deployed `WL Admin & Console services` using **Server Configuration Tool** wizard and `App Center` during WL installation.

I use Oracle JDK 1.7

[image]

Now when I try to access WL console it says `No runtime can be found`.

[image]

And if I access my App then: `Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.`

[image]

Though I **can see** in the logs that it shows `Application wladmin started in 13.173 seconds.`.

Besides, App Center works fine and I can upload an apk as well.

I've seen other questions on the same topic, but unfortunately none turned out to be helpful.

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518336/how-to-solve-management-service-not-starting-up-in-worklight-6-2) suggests to use Oracle JDK which I already use.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296532/no-runtime-can-be-found-in-worklight-console) suggests to upgrade Liberty version to fix the issue, but I
  am on the latest version... Or should I roll-back to an older one?
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391804/no-runtime-on-my-worklight-6-2-console) suggests to delete Liberty workarea and this did not help
  as well.
- and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333005/no-mbean-found-for-worklight-project) suggests a possible duplicate of WL Admin services war
  file and it is also not the case.

**Liberty server.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>

        <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
        <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


        <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight installer. -->
        <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight installer. -->

    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" host="*" >

        <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
        <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight installer. -->
        <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

    </httpEndpoint>

<!--
    IBM Worklight requires SSL and declared the "defaultKeyStore" default keystore. 
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    This configuration is the minimum one that you need to create an SSL configuration.
    With this configuration, the Liberty server creates the keystore and the certificate, 
    if it does not exist yet, during the SSL initialization.
    The created certificate is a self-signed certificate that is valid for 365 days.
    Do not use the certificates that the Liberty server created for production use.
    For more information see  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html
-->
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>

    <administrator-role>
        <!--    Worklight JMX User.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
        -->
        <user>WorklightRESTUser</user>

    </administrator-role>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="9443"/>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="WorklightRESTUser"/>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="Dq7ctngFgySc"/>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value="Liberty"/>
    <!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone"/>

    <basicRegistry>
        <!--    Worklight user.
        [Added by IBM Worklight Installation Manager for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
        -->
        <user name="appcenteradmin" password="admin"/>

        <!--    IBM Application Center group.
        [Added by IBM Worklight Installation Manager for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
        -->
        <group name="appcentergroup">
            <!--    IBM Application Center group member.
            [Added by IBM Worklight Installation Manager for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
            -->
            <member name="demo"/>

            <!--    IBM Application Center group member.
            [Added by IBM Worklight Installation Manager for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
            -->
            <member name="appcenteradmin"/>

        </group>

        <!--    Worklight user.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
        -->
        <user name="WorklightRESTUser" password="Dq7ctngFgySc"/>

        <!--    Worklight user.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
        [Added by IBM Worklight Installation Manager for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
        -->
        <user name="demo" password="demo"/>

    </basicRegistry>

    <!--    WebContainer statement.
        [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>

    <!-- Element <executor> added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for id 'wladmin'. -->
    <executor id="default" name="LargeThreadPool"
              coreThreads="200" maxThreads="400" keepAlive="60s"
              stealPolicy="STRICT" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


    <!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->

    <!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Service application. -->
    <application id="wladmin" name="wladmin" location="worklightadmin.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="demo"/>

            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            </security-role>

        </application-bnd>

        <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="wladmin/OracleLib">
            <commonLibrary id="worklightlib_wladmin">

                <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.8.jar"/>
            </commonLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Service. -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wladmin/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"WorklightServer"'/>


    <!-- Declare the jar files for Oracle access through JDBC. -->
    <library id="wladmin/OracleLib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/wladmin/oracle" includes="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </library>

    <!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Administration database. -->
    <dataSource jndiName="wladmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="wladmin/OracleLib"/>
        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem" user="WLADMIN" password="WLADMIN"/>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Console application. -->
    <application id="wlconsole" name="wlconsole" location="worklightconsole.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="worklightadmin">
                <user name="demo"/>

            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            </security-role>

            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            </security-role>

        </application-bnd>

    </application>

    <!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Console. -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="wlconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/wladmin"'/>


    <!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


    <!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight installer. -->

    <!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Console application. -->
    <application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
                <group name="appcentergroup"/>
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
    </application>

    <!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Services application. -->
    <application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
                <group name="appcentergroup"/>
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
        <classloader delegation="parentLast">
            <commonLibrary>
                <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.jar"/>
            </commonLibrary>
        </classloader>
    </application>

    <!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Application Center. -->

    <!-- Define the AppCenter services endpoint in order for the AppCenter console to be able to invoke the REST service.
            You need to enable this property if the server is behind a reverse proxy
            or if the context root of the Application Center Services application is different from '/applicationcenter'. -->
    <!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint" value='"http://proxyhost:proxyport/applicationcenter"'/> -->
    <!-- The directory with binaries of the 'aapt' program, from the Android SDK's platform-tools package. -->
    <jndiEntry jndiName="android.aapt.dir" value='"D:/IBM WL Server/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk"'/>
    <!-- The protocol of the application resources URI. This property is optional. It is only needed if the protocol of the external and internal URI are different. -->
    <!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol" value='"http"'/> -->
    <!-- The hostname of the application resources URI. -->
    <!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.host" value='"proxyhost"'/> -->
    <!-- The port of the application resources URI. This property is optional. -->
    <!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.port" value="proxyport"/> -->

    <!-- Declare the jar files for Oracle access through JDBC. -->
    <library id="OracleLib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <!-- Declare the IBM Application Center database. -->
    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem" user="WLAPPCENTER" password="WLAPPCENTER"/>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight installer. -->


    <!-- my App settings goes below  -->
    <application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="ADWEA.war" type="war"  context-root="/worklight" >

        <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="worklight/OracleLib">
            <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_worklight">
              <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
              <!-- <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/> -->
            </privateLibrary>
        </classloader>          

    </application>


    <dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/OracleLib"/>
        <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem" user="WRKLIGHT" password="WRKLIGHT"/>
    </dataSource>

    <dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
            <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/OracleLib"  />
            <properties.oracle driverType="thin" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem" user="WLRREPOR" password="wlrrepor"  />
    </dataSource> 

</server>
```

Here are the **Liberty console logs**:

```
D:\IBM WL Server\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin>server run WorklightServer
Launching WorklightServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version
1.7.0_75-b13 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server WorklightServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liber
ty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Libe
rty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere
/Liberty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liber
ty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere
/Liberty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liber
ty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Libe
rty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere
/Liberty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/applicationcenter.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_jaxb-1.0.2.0-20110217.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liber
ty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere
/Liberty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Lib
erty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/apps/worklightconsole.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/worklight/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/appcenterconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/wlconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application appcenterconsole started in 5.938 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application wlconsole started in 5.609 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/applicationcenter/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rat
her than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather
 than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rathe
r than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/wladmin/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rat
her than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather
 than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rath
er than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rathe
r than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] FWLSE0193W: JNDI resource jdbc/WorklightDS is not mapped to data-source, database URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem
will be used. Note that using wl.db.url is deprecated in production and won't be supported by future versions of MobileFirst. Make sure you
map data sources to MobileFirst's resource references through the server's configuration file (or console) [project worklight]
[err] dataBaseFromDataSource=true
[err] dataBaseUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.110.1.194:1529:gmaxem
[err] dataBaseDriver=Oracle JDBC driver
[err] dataBaseDriverVersion=11.2
[err] dataBaseProduct=Oracle
[err] dataBaseVersion=Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[err] dataBaseUser=WLAPPCENTER
[err] 94  appcenterdb-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-11] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 187  appcenterdb-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-11] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.Or
acleDictionary".
[err] 62  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-14] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 218  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-14] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.j
dbc.sql.OracleDictionary".
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application applicationcenter started in 12.532 seconds.
[err] 1390  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-14] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions,
 OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application wladmin started in 13.173 seconds.
[err] 32  WorklightPU  WARN   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with Pers
istenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/lib/worklight-jee-libra
ry.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be ava
ilable.
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.path'
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'ssl.keystore.password'
[err] 1360  WorklightPU  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 1391  WorklightPU  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "com.worklight.database.WorklightOrac
leDictionary".
[err] 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [LargeThreadPool-thread-10] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer wit
h PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/D:/IBM%20WL%20Server/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/lib/workli
ght-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation wi
ll not be available.
[WARNING ] Impossible to decode the password
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application worklight started in 18.563 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-1.0, jdbc-4.0, ldapRegistry-3.0, ssl-1.0, json-1.0, appSecu
rity-2.0, jsp-2.2, restConnector-1.0, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, distributedMap-1.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server WorklightServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[err] 20735  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-125] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[err] 20735  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-125] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjp
a.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary".
```

**Liberty Server Logs** (taken from `usr\servers\WorklightServer\logs` path)

Please this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/r1y4ZwWw) due to question character size limit.

Comment: Might be worth while to add your server.xml

Comment: Can you post the end of our Liberty log file ? I would expect to see issues or messages related to the communication between the runtime and the admin service that would help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @DidierVidal, please have a look on the given Pastebin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I should have spot the issue with the server.xml only.

The Server Configuration Tool systematically adds an environment ID. In your case, that one:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="wladmin/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"WorklightServer"'/>
```

It seems you installed the runtime (Project WAR file) manually or with a different tool. It must have the same environmentId value as specified here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_manually.html
(section before you begin)

Solution (step 6 of the manual install procedure listed above):
Add this JNDI Entry to your server.xml, for the worklight application:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"WorklightServer"'/>
```

Comment: Great, I added this line and it worked well : Thank You... Now I can see the console and have deployed .wlapp as well.