# mobile first platform cli: mfp build... does not create a war file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

My setup

MobileFrist Platform foundation 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357
WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 (1.0.3.20130510-0831) 
on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_75-b13 (en_US)
hosted on softlayer

Installed using this knowledge center guide for 6.3

after starting the server I can visit my appcenterconsole fine.

I have 2 issues now that I can't seem to understand:

Firstly, tried to build the Myproject.war file using MFP cli to deploy the server configuration tool. However Mfp build produced all the .wlapps but no war file. Can I build a .war file using mfp build?

Secondly, built the .war file using eclipse on my local machine tried to deploy it using the server config tool and I end up with no runtime found like in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075951/mobilefirst-wl-6-3-liberty-8-5-5-5-latest-no-runtime-can-be-found-in-wor)

So I checked my java version that was fine, 
checked app center version seems fine,
and checked the entries in server.xml for duplicates of WL Admin services war, only one exists.

server.xml http://pastebin.com/gXqfVknb
logs too long and paste bin counts as en extra link limited to 2 will post link to logs as comment

Comment: should I upgrade to the latest version of appcenter perhaps? from 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.5(latest)?

Comment: There is no relation between MFP Server (and the runtime that you're missing - the missing .war file) and the Application Center. Do not mix the two. Where is the server log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nLXqhZWG

Comment: See Nathan's reply. That's how you generate the .war file from the CLI

Comment: I get the following error on mfp bd                                             C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst-CLI\mobilefirst-cli\node_modules\generator-worklight-server\lib\build.xml:380: Element <project> inside <configureApplicationServer>: File 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Round\myapp/bin/myapp.war' does not exist.

Total time: 1 second
Error: Build process failed. Please check the stack above for details.
Error: Project's runtime is not available in the server.
Error: Restart the server by running 'mobilefirst restart' from the current folder.

Comment: mfp bd does the trick. think something is up with my app mfp bd gave errors on the app I want to deploy but not a test hello app I just made. Thanks nathan - will try to figure out the no runtime issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mfp bd` (build & deploy) instead of just `build`.

It will start a test server to generate the WAR file.